# Computer runs out of memory even though I have 8gb in Standby RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have an i5 12gb RAM Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit machine and I recently had to kill several processes because it ran out of 'Free Memory'...however there was still 7.5gb in 'Standby' Memory.

I didn't have that much open (Outlook, VS2010, SQL Server) but not really running any of them. Iwas typing an email and it just stopped.

I killed VS and SQL Server and then it slowly recovered...my question is if I have nearly 8gb of Standby memory not being used why does it run out of memory and die and can I somehow adjust the amount of memory

thanks

Comment: one cause could be wrongly configured pagefile

Answer (score 5):

1 possibility, Poorly coded programs may not release memory when it is needed by other processes, or the program has a memory leak.

Open a run box and type in resmon , then go to the memory tab, see what is using all the memory.

You can also install and run [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229) it gives a better display than resmon and has much more information to help solve the problem.

Some insight on [how to use RAMMap](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/50c7b6f1-15a1-4bdb-bd13-443e12a37e46/)

Also check your pagefile size.

Comment: Ahhhh I'd forgotten this little gem. Comes in handy!

Comment: Sorry , but It is not the responsibility of any program to " release memory when it is needed by other processes". Programs have no way of knowing when that is the case, unless they actively check performance counters such as page fault rates. Nobody is expected to do that.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it is probably the absence of a page file. I have been having the same problem since I have disabled the page file on my workstation. I have 32GB of RAM, and after two or three days without a reboot, my standby memory usage is up to 29 GB, and my system starts grinding to a halt. It seems Windows x64 does not always gracefully release the standby memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are some prudent things you can try to see if it will help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Ways-to-improve-your-computers-performance

But you're not running that much, so I think that Moab may be onto something where there may be some poorly coded programs.